# Creating application on Windows platform which enters to the secure area of website

Tags: c#, c++, windows, authentication

First of all, sorry for my English :)

I'm web developer. Generally coding in PHP.

Recently started to learn C++.

I want to create simple application which will simplfy daily routine works. For ex,Every time when I check my internet banking account, must login to my account via any browser. What I wanna do is, to create mini windows application which will store my login and pass, will login to my account, and show exact page what I see on browser directly after login. Website that I'm talking about is [here](https://www.hbservice.com/frontend/frontend)

The problem, I can't find any tutorial about creating such application. Don't know where to start. Did research but found nothing about this. (Maybe I selected wrong keywords :)) So decided to post question here. I don't need your code, just give me starting point, where to learn to create applications as I described above.

And one more question: Is it important to know website's coding language before building such windows apps?  I mean: PHP/C#... etc
Thx in advance

Comment: your question is vague and not for StackOverflow. What you want to do is already done. You have to google for log in to website programmatically like this link: https://www.google.com/search?q=login+website+programmatically

Comment: That's question about choosing browser plugin, not C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you would pick C++ for this type of project, though it's possible, it would be quite tedious. I would recommend looking into Java, perl, ruby, python, or some other language that supports the Selenium Webdriver API. You can also use the mechanize API with Perl, which is also a bit tedious. I've done things like this in the past with success using Selenium (http://seleniumhq.org). Unfortunately, I don't think there is a Webdriver API for C++ as of yet (you could try writing one!), but there are definitely APIs available for the other languages I posted. Check out: http://seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.html#programming-languages.

### EDIT

If you're more interested in screen scraping with C++, this question, and some answers within the thread, may prove useful to you as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489522/library-recommendation-c-html-parser

Comment: Though I might add, this is not a C++ specific question or answer. But, hopefully this answer will throw you in the right direction.